# Vuex inside nuxt app throws "Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers"!

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

In my NUXT app I am using vuex store modules! When I run the app and call

```
this.$store.dispatch('userStore/setLoggedInUser',currentUser); //default.vue
```

I get an error saying "Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers" that loops infinitely!

My module looks like this:

```
const actions = {
  setLoggedInUser({commit},currentUser){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      commit('mutateLoggedInUser',currentUser);
      resolve();
    });
  }
}

const mutations = {
  mutateLoggedInUser(state,user){
    state.loggedInUser = user;
  }
}
```

I found a solution (sort of). 
By setting strict mode to false in the store/index.js file the error disappears.

```
export const strict = false
```

But this seems like a hacky solution and I dont really understand whats going on. Is this a bug in NUXT or am I doing something weird in my vuex store?

Comment: Never seen/used a plain `return;` in a mutation. I'm just curious about if removing it will cease the error to fire. Sure this error seems weird.

Comment: No, it didn't :/ Added it to try to get rid of the error...

Comment: Are you sure the issue is this code? This looks fine.

Comment: Unlikely it's the code causing issue. Maybe someehere else u have some watcher ..

Comment: Have you tried calling the mutation directly instead of calling the action? And see if the error persists

Answer (score 8):

This error usually occurs if you're watching the passed in value somewhere which causes an infinite update loop but if you're not watching, it could be due to you passing in the original value rather than a copy.

Try changing:
`state.loggedInUser = user` to `state.loggedInUser = user.slice()`
or
`this.$store.dispatch('userStore/setLoggedInUser',currentUser.slice())`

Comment: What does the slice function do?

Comment: @AbingPj it creates a shallow copy of an array. It can take start and end parameters to specify a certain section of the array but in this case, without them, it will copy the entire array.